# How to reuse array functions in an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, infinite-loop

The real code is larger, so I won't post it. It looks pretty much like this:

```
class A {
    process(source) {
        // I perform several operations with array helper functions here:
        const filtered = source.filter(item => item);
        const condition = filtered.some(item => item);

        if (condition) {
            const mapped = source.map(item => /* Mapping operations... */);
            const sorted = mapped.sort((a, b) => { /* Some sort conditions... */ });
            return sorted;
        } else {
            const mapped2 = filtered.map(item => /* A different mapping operation... */);
            return mapped2;
        }
    }
}

const a = new A();

while (true) {
    const source = getSourceFromSomewhere(); // Array (40 - 50 items aprox)
    const b = a.process(source);
    // ...
}
```

> The problem: Basically, performance; "Don't make functions within a loop".

On every iteration a bunch of anonymous functions are getting created.

My solution:

```
class A {
    // Predefine it:
    sort() { /* Sort logic */ }
    map() { /* Map logic */ }
    map2() { /* Map logic */ }
    filter() { /* Filter logic */ }
    some() { /* Condition */ }

    process(source) {
        const filtered = source.filter(this.filter); // Note: Scope of 'this' is changed.
        const condition = filtered.some(this.some);

        if (condition) {
            const mapped = source.map(this.map);
            const sorted = mapped.sort(this.sort);
            return sorted;
        } else {
            const mapped2 = filtered.map(this.map2);
            return mapped2;
        }
    }
}
```

> Another problem: Some of this functions need access to properties of the object itself, but the scope of `this` has been changed.

It's worth to call `.bind(this)` instead of creating the anonymous function? or pretty much the same?

What would you do in my case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To initialize bound functions within a class you could do

```
class Test {
    fn = (t) => this[t]
}
```

basically the same what you wanted to do anyways.

Comment: I do not understand how this is supposed to work. Where would `fn` be invoked? How would `fn('foo')` be different from `this.foo`? Won't the `this` inside `fn` be the surrounding `this`, instead of the `this` of the class?

Answer (score 1):

> The problem: Basically, performance; "Don't make functions within a loop".

Your premise is incorrect.

JavaScript engines are highly optimized. They do not laboriously read the source text character-by-character each time through a loop, or each time a function is called, much less each time a callback is invoked. They scan, parse, and pre-compile. At worst, functions like `item => item` will be created only once per function invocation. More likely, they will be pre-created during the initial scanning and parsing process.

Therefore, you don't need to worry about performance when considering whether to pre-define the functions yourself. The guiding principle should instead be program readability and structure.

If you do want to pre-define a function, as long as it does not use `this`, consider defining it outside the class:

```
function filterFunc(item) { return item.val < MAX; }

class A {
  process() {
    const filtered = source.filter(filterFunc);
```

If you do need 'this`, then in modern JS it is preferable to write

```
class A {
  filterFunc(item) { return item.val < this.MAX; }

  process() {
    const filtered = source.filter(item => this.filterFunc(item));
```

instead of worrying about binding `this.filterFunc` making you write

```
class A {
  constructor () { this.filterFunc = this.filterFunc.bind(this); }

  process() {
    const filtered = source.filter(this.filterFunc);
```

Answer (score 1):

While as mentioned in another answer

```
class Test {
    // constructor etc.
    step = x => x + this.currentStep;
    process() {
        return this.arr.map(step);
    }
}
```

would be a concise way to achieve your intended behavior, as `this` is already bound to the instance, it requires public class fields which is still in Stage 2, and therefore not yet supported in many browsers without a transpiler.

It is good to remember that you can always **pass the `this` scope to the second argument of functions such as `map` and `filter`**, so you don't have to manually bind your functions beforehand. The code then becomes

```
class Test {
    // constructor etc.
    step(x) { return x + this.currentStep; }
    process() {
        return this.arr.map(step, this);
    }
}
```

This is very close to the solution you have in mind while making sure your functions have the correct scope.

Though I don't know much about inner workings of browsers I think if the code is hot enough (that is being ran often), the optimized compiler might not need to recreate those anonymous functions every run.